# How to autoplay a youtube clip in a banner?

Tags: youtube, opencart

Programs:Opencart 2.3.0.2, journal 2.

Hello, I have a youtube clip on a banner that I have placed on my websides Home-menu. I want this clip to start playing as soon as someone opens the webpage.
I know that to make a youtube clip play automatically on a productpage you change the autoplay variable from 0 to 1, but I can not find a corresponding autoplay variable for the clip on my banner.

Any solutions out here from someone more experienced than me?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I am not using HTML5 or Vimeo, I have copied the Url directly from Youtube.

Comment: You are using HTML5 whether you think you are or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the variable in your YouTube Link this way:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VideoIDhere?autoplay=1&mute=1
```

Don't forget the `mute=1` argument for the [2018 Autoplay Policy Changes as described on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50272974/3623080).

Comment: Is that when you use HTML5, I am currently using a Url from Youtube?

Comment: It shall work on any link provided by YouTube, just add the " ?autoplay=1 " at the end of your link.

Comment: It does not seem to work. my youtube link looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T.....

Comment: Sorry, then it will also depend on the way Open Cart transform your Link to be embeded. If you look at the source code of your page you should find your video with the embed link.

Answer (score -1):

Just put "?autoplay=1" in the url the video will autoload

Comment: This doesn't say anything the other answer doesn't say.  The other answer says that just `autoplay=1` isn't sufficient.   `mute=1` also need sot be there because of new rules made in 2018.  It is possible that you are trying to say that things have changed again and that the `mute` is no longer needed, if so you should say so and link to a reference.   Otherwise your answer is redundant and unclear.